# Map value range to rainbow-colormap

Tags: c++, colormap

I need a function that maps the v to the rainbow colors from red to violet. Precise said:

```
(rRB,gRB,bRB) = mapping_fct(v)
```

with **v ϵ [0, a]**, where 0 should be red and a violet.

Is there anything existing (didn't find anything so far)?
I'm coding in C++

Comment: What is mapping_fct ?

Comment: What is the input of mapping_fct? An enumeration or just a simple integer?

Comment: if you want a continuous spectrum, [a] should actually map to red so that it wraps around. 0 = red, a*1/3 = green, a*2/3 = blue, a = red

Comment: In the text you say you want to map from RGB to rainbow colors, but your formula seems to be mapping from rainbow colors to RGB. Which one do you want? Conversion between rainbow colors in range \[0,1) and RGB can be done using the [HSV or HSL color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Comment: @maddin45: Yes sorry. I'm look for a function that maps a value in a linear interval to a triple of rgb values that combine to a rainbow color. E.g: f(0.1) = [254, 0, 0 ] or f(0.3) = [92, 181, 4] if v [0,1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this function, which has linear interpolation and wraps around to red->green->blue->red. np is your maximum value (a) and p is the input value (v). You could get it to stop at violet by increasing np a bit so that p is always less than np.

```
void getcolor(int p, int np, float&r, float&g, float&b) {
    float inc = 6.0 / np;
    float x = p * inc;
    r = 0.0f; g = 0.0f; b = 0.0f;
    if ((0 <= x && x <= 1) || (5 <= x && x <= 6)) r = 1.0f;
    else if (4 <= x && x <= 5) r = x - 4;
    else if (1 <= x && x <= 2) r = 1.0f - (x - 1);
    if (1 <= x && x <= 3) g = 1.0f;
    else if (0 <= x && x <= 1) g = x - 0;
    else if (3 <= x && x <= 4) g = 1.0f - (x - 3);
    if (3 <= x && x <= 5) b = 1.0f;
    else if (2 <= x && x <= 3) b = x - 2;
    else if (5 <= x && x <= 6) b = 1.0f - (x - 5);
}
```

Example usage:

```
float r,g,b;
getcolor(545, 1024, r, g, b);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exact what I was looking for!