# Fill array dynamicly with gradient color c++

Tags: c++, arrays, colors, linear-gradients

what I'm trying to do is fill an array with an rainbow gradient. The array should hold 256 entries an filled with the hex value of colors.

[image: rainbow]

like:

```
array[0] = 0xFF0000 //red
...
array[85] = 0xFFA200 //orange
...
array[170] = 0x00AF0F //green
...
array[255] = 0xAE00FF //purple
```

because I do not want to assign all 256 colors "by hand" to the array I'm looking for an dynamicly approach for that. It's not necessarily need to be the ranbow displayed above. The picture is just for demonstration purpose.

Any suggestions how to do things like this in an (preferably) short code snipit avoiding a couple of nested for loops?

Comment: _" It's not necessarily need to be the rainbow displayed above"_ So random 256 values ?

Comment: @P0W more like it needs to be a rainbow but not exactly that one I would assume.

Comment: Hint: Hex values may seem hard to modify, but in fact each color is a combination of 3 integers (R,G,B).

Comment: Possible duplicate question, read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876316/map-value-range-to-rainbow-colormap/37877160#37877160

Comment: Interpolate in a more suitable colour space than RGB (HSV) and then convert.

Comment: @P0W / @Borgleader yes a rainbow / various color gradient fading from one color to another / more than one others
@Sven Nilsson thx for that but your `r,g,b` are just returning `0.sth` and not positive integer values between 0 and 255. So I'm unsure how they would help me :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We want to go from:

```
red -> yellow
yellow -> green
green -> cyan
cyan -> blue
blue -> magenta
magenta -> red
```

In each pass, one of the `red`, `green`, `blue` components is always `0`, the second is `255`, and the third is increasing or decreasing between `0` and `255`.

In other words:

```
{255,  0,    0} -> {255, 255,   0} grn increases to 255
{255, 255,   0} -> {  0, 255,   0} red decreases to 0
{0  , 255,   0} -> {  0, 255, 255} blu increases to 255
{0  , 255, 255} -> {  0,   0, 255} grn decreases to 0
{0  ,   0, 255} -> {255,   0, 255} red increases to 255
{255,   0, 255} -> {255,   0,   0} blu decreases to 0
```

This produces 256 * 6 colors, we may not want all of those colors, so it has to be normalized. This can be done with following code:

```
//input: ratio is between 0.0 to 1.0
//output: rgb color
uint32_t rgb(double ratio)
{
    //we want to normalize ratio so that it fits in to 6 regions
    //where each region is 256 units long
    int normalized = int(ratio * 256 * 6);

    //find the region for this position
    int region = normalized / 256;

    //find the distance to the start of the closest region
    int x = normalized % 256;

    uint8_t r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
    switch (region)
    {
    case 0: r = 255; g = 0;   b = 0;   g += x; break;
    case 1: r = 255; g = 255; b = 0;   r -= x; break;
    case 2: r = 0;   g = 255; b = 0;   b += x; break;
    case 3: r = 0;   g = 255; b = 255; g -= x; break;
    case 4: r = 0;   g = 0;   b = 255; r += x; break;
    case 5: r = 255; g = 0;   b = 255; b -= x; break;
    }
    return r + (g << 8) + (b << 16);
}
```

Usage:

```
double range = 500.0;
for (double i = 0; i < range; i++)
{
    uint32_t color = rgb(i / range);
    ...
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: great! exactly what I was looking for! Now the rgb color generation makes even sense for me. lovely

Comment: maybe consider using `uint8_t` for RGB colors (unsigned 0 - 255)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do what you want is to interpolate each of the component colours (RGB) from their starting to their ending value. This means using steps that are of as equal size as possible.

To get the RGB components some bit manipulation is necessary. This code gives you the three component colours for a fully-stated colour `fullColour`:

```
std::array<float, 3> colourRGB;

for(unsigned i = 0; i<3; ++i) {
    colourRGB[i] = (fullColour & (0xFF << (i*8))) >> (i*8);
```

You use this to get the RGB array of your starting and ending colour (for example, for the red-orange range in your example this would be the RGB breakdown of `0xFF0000` and `0xFFA200`). For each component you then work out the step size required for each step in your 'fade'. This is given by the total change in that component divided by the total number of steps. For the red-orange example the step size for the Red component would thus be 1.91 (because you have 86 steps and a total change of (`0xA2` - `0x00`, or 162 in decimal, yielding 162/86=1.91). The step sizes for the other components are zero as they don't change.

You can then iterate over the steps, at each one adding another step size and rounding to get the new value for each component. For example, at step `s`:

```
red[s] = startingRed + ((float)s * stepSizeRed)
```

To re-combine your rgb values back into a full colour, just apply some bit manipulation again:

```
fullColour[s] = 0;
for(unsigned i=0; i<3; ++i)
    fullColour[s] += rgbComponent[s][i] << (i*8);
```

This approach yields the required 'fade' from any starting to any ending colour in any number of steps.

Comment: thanks for that, but your code is roughly hard to understand, due to I'm unsure what e.g. `red[s]` or `startingRed` is and ist `colourRGB` the same as `fullColour` etc? It would be great if you can attach an "full"/"working" example of the red-orange sample you provided. cheers